# INotification handler is never called in MediatR

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, mediatr

I have an event called `SheetUpdatedEvent`. I want to call `SheetUpdatedEventHandler` when my `Sheet` is updated.

Here is my event:

```
 public class SheetUpdatedEvent : INotification
 {
     public string SheetId { get; set; }
     public SheetUpdatedEvent(string sheetId)
     {
         SheetId = sheetId;
     }
 }
```

Here is my handler:

```
public class SheetUpdatedEventHandler : INotificationHandler<SheetUpdatedEvent>
{
    private readonly IRedisCacheService _redisCacheService;

    public SheetUpdatedEventHandler(IRedisCacheService redisCacheService)
    {
        _redisCacheService = redisCacheService;
    }
    public Task Handle(SheetUpdatedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _redisCacheService.RemoveData($"sheet_{notification.SheetId}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In my codes, when my sheet is updated, I added the following code:

```
await _mediator.Publish(new SheetUpdatedEvent(sheetId));
```

in my Program.cs, I registered `MediatR` as follows:

```
  builder.Services.AddMediatR(config => config.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

but my event handler is never called.

**Update:** I created separate assemblies: Domain, Infrastructure, and WebAPI. `SheetUpdatedEventHandler` is in my Domain project. and I registered MediatR in a separate assembly (my WebAPI project).

When I move the `SheetUpdatedEventHandler` into the WebAPI project it is called. But I follow an architecture, in which I do not be allowed to move `SheetUpdatedEventHandler` in WebAPI assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code before `AddMediatR`.

```cs
_ = typeof(SheetUpdatedEventHandler);
```

This is probably because the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` returns the assemblies that are loaded and usually AddMediatR is in the startup and the assembly that your handler exists in is not loaded yet. Referencing a type in that assembly before `AddMediatR` triggers the assembly to load.